# Multiple Mysql Updates in one query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to update the same field over different rows using **PDO** and **MYSQL**, I generate a table with a statement and then pass the id & "result" (status update) to php, the following is the code for my table, but when I go to update, first it tells me there are to many bind params even when I input a value for all fields generated by the table and it still wont update the table!

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
<table width="auto" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tr>
<th class='col-md-1'>ID</th>
<th class='col-md-1'>User ID</th>
<th class='col-md-1'>Name</th>
<th class='col-md-1'>Date submited</th>
<th class='col-md-1'>Date Requested</th>
<th class='col-md-1'>Status</th>
</tr>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
$sth = $pdo->query($sql);
$count= $sth->rowCount();
while($row = $sth->fetch()) {

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['id']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['user_id']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Name']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['Date_submited']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['Date_requested']. "</td>";
echo "<td>" .$row['Status']. "</td>";
echo "<td> <select name='Status[]' value=''> <option disabled selected='true'>Please     Select</option>  <option value='denied'>Denied</option> <option value='approved'>Approved</option> </td>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='id[]' value='".$row['id']."' />";
echo "</tr>";
}

?>
<td>      <input type='submit' name='approve' class='btn btn-default' value='submit'/></td>
 </table>
 </form>
```

And this is my update query:

```
if (isset( $_POST['approve'] ) ){
$result = $_POST['Status'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$a = count($id);
try{
$sth = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE data 
                                SET 
                                Status = :Status
                                                WHERE id = :id              
                                ');
$i = 0; 
while ($i < $a) {
    $sth->bindParam(':Status', $result[$i]);
    $sth->execute();
    $i++;
    }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo "I'm sorry, but there was an error updating the database.";  
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
}
}
```

Comment: You're only binding one parameter, your query requires two.

Comment: "Status = :Status WHERE id = :id" where is the second paramter in that query ?

Comment: :Status is one, :id is the second one.

Comment: I thought you might say that!

Comment: "Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference"

Comment: Okay so now, nothing happens! "Notice: Array to string conversion"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the loop in the wrong place and you need to bind all of your query parameters -

```
if (isset( $_POST['approve'] ) ){
    // loop through results of post array
    for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['id']); $i++) {
        $result = $_POST['Status'][$i];
        $id = $_POST['id'][$i];
        try{
            $sth = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE data SET Status = :Status WHERE id = :id');
            $sth->bindParam(':Status', $result);
            $sth->bindParam(':id', $id);
            $sth->execute();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {  
            echo "I'm sorry, but there was an error updating the database.";  
            file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No im updating multiple records at one time for example the user might choose to approve 5 entrys at one time and then click submit, updating the records across more than one row!

Comment: if you have undefined offsets now it is because the action didn't pass the variables. Look at your underlying HTML in the first page and make sure the variables are being placed as you expect. You never execute the query in that page.

Comment: Is there a way to do this code without the user having to update every entry in one go?

Comment: What do you mean "variables are being placed as you expect."

Comment: I'm sure there is a way, but without know the goals of the system and what you're trying to accomplish it would be hard for me to say. Are the variables Status and ID populated in the actual hidden form fields and select statements?

Comment: Basicly in short, a user inputs a date they would like to take of work, its the seen by this admin table who then selects wether they approve them to take that day of work! My Html for the table appears the excat same way that it does in my question! Thank you for all the help btw and will be upvoting to the right answer as technically is the correct answer!

Comment: There should be a value in the hidden input for the id on each row. Is there?

Comment: "value='".$row['id']."'" Yes

Comment: Is it actually echoing out the id?

Comment: Yes it is! i know this because it echo's out erliar on in the table!

Comment: Sorry had to make the comment a certian length!